# Performance of searching through a list of items in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a list of approx. 2000 questions and I am trying to create an interface where you can filter through them all using a text input.

I tried going through [this React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) since i thought it would perform well enough but there is a considerable lag. Or at least there is when I run the code in an Electron container (perhaps I'd get better performance compiling it with Webpack). I just tried putting my code in to a jsfiddle and with 3000 elements the performance starts to suffer.

Is it futile trying to search through this many objects with html and js or is there a simpler way with better performance?

Comment: link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/owfs3vwp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the lag is not because of the filtering, but because you are trying to render too many objects in one hit. You can see this by typing a sequence of zeros into the filter input. Each zero typed requires less time, as obviously the result size gets smaller and smaller.

I have updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/07103wng/) to show the performance if you only render the first 100 items in the result set (even though all 3000 are processed on each input change).

Essentially I am just generating the full `rows` variable, and then using `.slice(0, 100)` to generate a truncated version before rendering.

What you should do in this situation is think about UI/UX, and that it really isn't necessary to render thousands of items at the same time. You could implement some sort of pagination or infinite scroll, etc.

Comment: Good point about the UX. I haven't really found a good way to navigate 2000 questions, but they are divided in sections so that could be a first step. I guess the idea is to not render the questions I cannot see anyway. 
Then again - something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hkwdw77c/ using jQuery seems to have decent performance .

Comment: While you *should* be able to get a few thousand rendering quickly, it really shouldn't be done that way. Users are only ever going to see `x` at a time, so things like infinite scroll can make the page appear as though it is rendering as many as you want without the processing overhead.

Comment: Also I found [clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/) which seems to fit my use case. [Example with search](http://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/zvBveE).

Comment: Thanks. And for React this might be a good place to look: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized